# How to avoid Eclipse open other layout when change the device?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, layout

I have an Android app and it has a layout that is duplicated in res->layout folder and in res->layout-xxhdpi. When the device is xxhdpi it uses the second layout and when its other resolution it uses default layout. It works good on real devices.

The problem is when I'm working in Eclipse and I want to change something on default layout. If I change the emulator device (on eclipse ide) to see the render it always open xxhdpi\layout. Is there anyway I could avoid eclipse to open the other layout and render the default layout with the screen I selected. I know if I select a xxhdpi device it must open the second layout but if I select a mpi device I would like to stay on default layout and render it. It is how it works on a real device.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well ,the fact is that virtual devices that you test on, work exactly as real-hardware devices.

Every verification is done in the same manner either you are on a real phone/tablet or you run a virtual device.

My advice would be this: run your application directly on a phone / tablet -I am pretty sure you can have them both connected ,as long as you got two USB ports free.And when you run the application, in the prompt you just choose which device you want.

There is no downside to this ,because your LogCat works with the real device too ,therefor testing is as proper as it can get.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. As you say, I'll expect that It works like real device. If I run the app on a 7" device (mdpi) it uses default layout (as I expected) and if I run it on a 5" device (xxhdpi) it uses the second layout. It works good on device. But my problem is on IDE when I need to change the layout to add new components. I can't work with default layout because it always open xxhdpi\layout when I select a mdpi screen.